# Python check variable against multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x

So I have 3 lists of data, I need to test if any of the data I get from the json response is in any of the lists, I'm probably being stupid about it but I'm trying to learn and can't seem to get it to work right.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
list2 = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']

#block of code...
#block of code...

content = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))
data = content
for x in data:
   #if x['name'] in list1: #This works fine the line below does not.
   if x['name'] in (list1, list2, list3):
   print("something")
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: It could be that it is checking to see if the value x['name'] matches fully and exactly any of the lists in (list1,list2,list3).

Comment: I was getting an "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something simple and straight-forward:

```
if (x['name'] in list1 or 
    x['name'] in list2 or 
    x['name'] in list3):
    ...
```

Comment: While I liked Kasramvd's suggestion, I am choosing this method for simplicity and me making sure I can remember what I'm doing later and not having to scratch my head trying to figure it out again.

Answer (score 1):

As a pythinc way for such tasks you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) for simulating the `OR` operand and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) for `and` operand.

So her you can use a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within `any()` :

```
if any(x['name'] in i for i in (list1, list2, list3))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about concatenating the lists?

```
if x['name'] in [list1 + list2 + list3]:
```

Comment: The downside is that this generates a new list object *every time the `if` statement is reached*. If the lists won't change, it is more efficient to move the concatenation outside the `for` loop.